# how to set the direction of vue-carousel-3d

Tags: javascript, vue.js, carousel

I want to set autoplay direction of left to right,
because Official api the default value is right to left: 

`dir
Animation direction
Type: String
Default: rtl`

so , I want to change this.
but not working, this is my code 
`<carousel-3d :autoplay="true" :dir=ltr >`

you can use this code pen [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/p2927k3p/279/)

official website :[enter link description here](https://wlada.github.io/vue-carousel-3d/examples/)

if you know this question,please tell me , thank you！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `dir="ltr"`

```
<carousel-3d :autoplay="true" dir="ltr" :autoplay-timeout="5000" :display="3" :perspective=0 >
</carousel-3d>
```

Demo https://jsfiddle.net/t107hLka/

Comment: ues your code is fixed this question . ￣□￣｜｜，thank's again for your answer 